# How to remove the link to the order in the admin order (plain) mail in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, email-notifications

I would like to remove the link in the plain text email to the admin of the shop, but keep the other information (total, paymenttype, delivery).

I found the template [`admin_new_order.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/admin-new-order.php) and the line but my research was not successful for the details.

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email );
```

---

How to find the available fields for total, payment type, delivery and link? How to remove the link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The code you are looking for can be found in the following template file
>
> [`emails/plain/email-customer-details.php`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/plain/email-order-details.php)
>
> - This template can be overridden by copying it to `yourtheme/woocommerce/emails/plain/email-order-details.php`.

In the copy you create of the template file you can remove: line [49 - 52](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/emails/plain/email-order-details.php#L49-L52)

```php
if ( $sent_to_admin ) {
    /* translators: %s: Order link. */
    echo "\n" . sprintf( esc_html__( 'View order: %s', 'woocommerce' ), esc_url( $order->get_edit_order_url() ) ) . "\n";
}
```